# Decode multiple images from URL in Swift 4

Tags: swift

I have an API endpoint that outputs 2 image URLs. I have the code below that decodes and parses through one of the image URLs, but I require to get and parse through both of the images.

How do I modify the code below so that the final return is 2 images

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

enum ApodImageResponse {
    case Success(image: UIImage, title: String)
    case Failure
}

struct ApodApiResponse: Decodable {
    var url: String
    var title: String
}

class ApodImageProvider {
    static func getImageFromApi(completion: ((ApodImageResponse) -> Void)?) {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        let date = Date()
        let urlString = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=eaRYg7fgTemadUv1bQawGRqCWBgktMjolYwiRrHK&date=\(formatter.string(from: date))"
        
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, urlResponse, error in
            parseResponseAndGetImage(data: data, urlResponse: urlResponse, error: error, completion: completion)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
    static func parseResponseAndGetImage(data: Data?, urlResponse: URLResponse?, error: Error?, completion: ((ApodImageResponse) -> Void)?) {
        
        guard error == nil, let content = data else {
            print("error getting data from API")
            let response = ApodImageResponse.Failure
            completion?(response)
            return
        }
        
        var apodApiResponse: ApodApiResponse
        do {
            apodApiResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApodApiResponse.self, from: content)
        } catch {
            print("error parsing URL from data")
            let response = ApodImageResponse.Failure
            completion?(response)
            return
        }
        
        let url = URL(string: apodApiResponse.url)!
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, urlResponse, error in
            parseImageFromResponse(data: data, urlResponse: urlResponse, error: error, apodApiResponse: apodApiResponse, completion: completion)
        }
        task.resume()
        
    }
    
    static func parseImageFromResponse(data: Data?, urlResponse: URLResponse?, error: Error?, apodApiResponse: ApodApiResponse, completion: ((ApodImageResponse) -> Void)?) {
        
        guard error == nil, let content = data else {
            print("error getting image data")
            let response = ApodImageResponse.Failure
            completion?(response)
            return
        }
        
        let image = UIImage(data: content)!
        let response = ApodImageResponse.Success(image: image, title: apodApiResponse.title)
        completion?(response)
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything in your code says you get 1 image from the api (and handles that one image), where does the second one come from? (And don't tag spam)

Comment: That is just an example URL from NASA api. I need to modify the code above to get 2 images

Comment: But how? Where does the second one come from? Are you making a second call to the api or are you using a different endpoint? We can't guess what you are thinking...

Comment: It is just another URL value inside the JSON response

Comment: Then change that property to be an array in your model and loop over that array after decoding the json. Why are you posting code for handling one type of API call when the question really is about another type of API call?

Comment: Sorry I am new to Swift, so example code would be really useful